# drawing a rectange over an image on canvas using dragging event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to draw a rectangle on an image using the mouse and dragging events on HTML5. 
My code is shown below. When I draw the rectangle below, the actual image on the canvas disappears. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? My intended goal is to have the rectangle on top of the image. I have attached a picture of what I actually want to see as the end result.

What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';

// ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
rect = {},
drag = false;
var rectStartXArray = new Array() ;
var rectStartYArray = new Array() ;
var rectWArray = new Array() ;
var rectHArray = new Array() ;

function init() {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    rect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    rect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    drag = true;
}
function mouseUp() {
    rectStartXArray[rectStartXArray.length] = rect.startX;
    rectStartYArray[rectStartYArray.length] = rect.startY;
    rectWArray[rectWArray.length] = rect.w;
    rectHArray[rectHArray.length] = rect.h;
    drag = false;
}

function mouseMove(e) {
  if (drag) {
        rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
        rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        draw();
    }

    //drawOldShapes();
}
function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
    ctx.stroke();
}
function drawOldShapes(){
    for(var i=0;i<rectStartXArray.length;i++)
    {
        if(rectStartXArray[i]!= rect.startX && rectStartYArray[i] != rect.startY && rectWArray[i] != rect.w && rectHArray[i] != rect.h)
        {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
            ctx.fillRect(rectStartXArray[i], rectStartYArray[i], rectWArray[i], rectHArray[i]);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
}
init();
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clearing the whole canvas inside `draw()` by calling `ctx.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);`. Remove the line and it works. Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/da8wv75k/

Comment: @AshwinVenkataraman. If this answer satisfies your question, you should click the checkmark green so your question is taken off the "unanswered" list on Stackoverflow. ;-)